# With Scrapy, How do I check links on a single page is allowed from robots.txt file?

Tags: python, scrapy

With Scrapy, I will scrape a single page (via script and not from console) to check all the links on this page if they are allowed by the `robots.txt` file.

In the `scrapy.robotstxt.RobotParser` abstract base class, I found the method [allowed(url, user_agent)](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.robotstxt.RobotParser.allowed), but I don't see how to use it.

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "TestSpider"

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestSpider, self).__init__()
               
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='http://httpbin.org/', callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        if 200 <= response.status < 300:
            links = scrapy.linkextractors.LinkExtractor.extract_links(response)
            for idx, link in enumerate(links):
                    # How can I check each link is allowed by robots.txt file?
                    # => allowed(link.url , '*')    
                    
                    # self.crawler.engine.downloader.middleware.middlewares
                    # self.crawler AttributeError: 'TestSpider' object has no attribute 'crawler'
```

To run 'TestSpider' spider, in `settings.py` set

```
# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
```

Go to the project’s top level directory and run:

> scrapy crawl TestSpider

Appreciate any help.

***My solution:***

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt import RobotsTxtMiddleware
from scrapy.utils.httpobj import urlparse_cached
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "TestSpider"

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestSpider, self).__init__()
        self.le = LinkExtractor(unique=True, allow_domains=self.allowed_domains)
        self._rules = [
            Rule(self.le, callback=self.parse)
        ]

    def start_requests(self):
        self._robotstxt_middleware = None
        for middleware in self.crawler.engine.downloader.middleware.middlewares:
            if isinstance(middleware, RobotsTxtMiddleware):
                self._robotstxt_middleware = middleware
break

        yield scrapy.Request(url='http://httpbin.org/', callback=self.parse_robotstxt)

    def parse_robotstxt(self, response):
        robotstxt_middleware = None
        for middleware in self.crawler.engine.downloader.middleware.middlewares:
            if isinstance(middleware, RobotsTxtMiddleware):
                robotstxt_middleware = middleware
                break

        url = urlparse_cached(response)
        netloc = url.netloc
        self._robotsTxtParser = None
        if robotstxt_middleware and netloc in robotstxt_middleware._parsers:
                self._robotsTxtParser = robotstxt_middleware._parsers[netloc]
       
        return self.parse(response)

    def parse(self, response):
        if 200 <= response.status < 300:
            links = self.le.extract_links(response)
            for idx, link in enumerate(links):
                # Check if link target is forbidden by robots.txt
                if self._robotsTxtParser:
                    if not self._robotsTxtParser.allowed(link.url, "*"):
                        print(link.url,' Disallow by robotstxt file')
```

Answer (score 4):

Parser implementations are listed a bit higher on the page than the link you posted.

> **Protego parser**
>
> Based on [Protego](https://github.com/scrapy/protego):
>
> - implemented in Python
> - is compliant with Google’s Robots.txt Specification
> - supports wildcard matching
> - uses the length based rule
>
> Scrapy uses this parser by default.

So, if you want the same results as scrapy gives by default, use protego.

The usage is as follows (`robotstxt` being the contents of a robots.txt file):

```
>>> from protego import Protego
>>> rp = Protego.parse(robotstxt)
>>> rp.can_fetch("http://example.com/profiles", "mybot")
False
```

It is also possible to identify and reuse the robots middleware currently in use, but it's probably more trouble than it's worth for most use cases.

**Edit:**

If you *really* want to reuse the middleware, your spider has access to downloader middlewares through `self.crawler.engine.downloader.middleware.middlewares`.
From there, you need to identify the robots middleware (possibly by class name?) and the parser you need (from the middleware's `_parsers` attribute).
Finally, you'd use the parser's `can_fetch()` method to check your links.

Comment: Yes I want the same results as scrapy gives by default with Protego. But Protego doesn't have fetch method like reppy to to get the contents of a robots.txt file
That's why I want to reuse the robots middleware to get the same result as Scrapy.

Comment: Edited to include an overview of how to reuse the middleware.

Comment: `self.crawler` AttributeError: 'TestSpider' object has no attribute 'crawler'

Comment: Weird, it works for me, and I can't see anything in scrapy's changelog that would suggest this was changed at any point...

Comment: You should update your question with your current code, at this point I don't know what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: On my setup, the code in the question throws a `TypeError` when I run it directly and runs fine after I fix the error, so I'm afraid I can't help you more.

Comment: I finally found out why I had the error: `self.crawler AttributeError:`
I continue my investigations in order to propose a solution.